# React Native - Xcode - DerivedData - Pods - ExpoModules

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

How exactly does xcode or xcode pods get cached?

I've made changes to update react native, or every time I make expo changes, or certain packages. My project is not an expo project but I am using the expo SDK.

Expo 44-45, React Native 67.3 trying to update to 68.5

My pod install command installs all the wrong dependencies.

I get CompileC  --> DerivedData or iPhone Deployment Target errors or Simulator cached issues.

I delete derived data and everything, still pod installs all the wrong pods.

I know the cause of the errors, but I'm not sure why if I run npm i and pod install it installs all of a previous cached pods.

Now I'm getting:

````
Error: Command failed: xcrun simctl list --json devices
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/me/repos/MobileApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:167:54)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/me/repos/MobileApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:121:12)
    at Command.handleAction (/Users/me/repos/MobileApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:23)
    at Command.listener (/Users/me/repos/MobileApp/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Command.parseArgs (/Users/me/repos/MobileApp/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/Users/me/repos/MobileApp/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)```
````

Comment: How's that you deleted `cached pods`, and you get cached-pods installed on `pod install`?

Comment: Delete the pod lock file

Comment: In xcode Encountered error communicating with IBAgent-iOS

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove **pod folder** and **podfile.lock file** in iOS folder.
2. run this command `pod install`

Comment: tried this now I get unable to find utility simctl, not a developer tool or in PATH

Comment: Try this command: `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running a react-native app (without expo). I pressed the button "Clean build folder" and then XCode wouldn't find files from the DerivedData folder. I did tried what [Samuel Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74891408) said, and deleted cached pods, but still had the same error.

What ended up solving the issue for me was restarting my laptop.

And then running:

```
cd /ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod install
```

After that, I opened XCode, waited until the project built and indexed itself. And finally ran the app (Pressing the button "Start the active scheme")

Answer (score 0):

These issues often result from a combination of caching mechanisms, build artifacts, and dependency versioning.

The **npm** caches packages to improve installation speed. Sometimes, the cache might not get invalidated properly, leading to the installation of outdated dependencies. Running `npm cache clean -f` helps in such cases.

**CocoaPods** also has its own cache. Running pod install may not always clear the cache completely. Manually deintegrating and reinstalling pods (`pod deintegrate`, `pod install`) can be more effective.